# Flow/Typescript Verifying HTML Element type from string

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I'm looking for a standard way using Flow/React/ReactDOM to verify that a string is a valid html element type.

I'm 99% there using this

```
const generateComponent = (ComponentString: $Keys<$JSXIntrinsics>, styleObject) => {
  return <ComponentString foo="bar" />
}

const ValidComponent = generateComponent('div');
const ShouldThrowErrorComponent = generateComponent('divv');
```

However flow's "catchall" string makes any string a valid html element.

There's gotta be an established way of doing this with typescript/flow, right?
My goal is to avoid writing my own custom list like [this](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/packages/styled-components/src/utils/domElements.js)
And instead use an established library like [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.104.0/lib/react-dom.js#L269)

but without line 271 `[string]: ReactDOM$HTMLElementJSXIntrinsic,` breaking the explicit checking

Comment: I don't think there's a way to pull out the DOM element names with Flow utility types. I think the best you can do (without maintaining your own list or finding another maintained list on npm) is to write a preprocessor that grabs the keys without `[string]` from [`react-dom.js`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.104.0/lib/react-dom.js) or the `tagName`s from [`dom.js`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.104.0/lib/dom.js).